# jQuery convert current (and future) input to datepicker

Tags: jquery

With jquery I know how to convert all the present input to datepickers (this occurs in a `$(document).ready` event):

```
$('.date').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({ ... });
});
```

My question is: How can I do it even for future datepickers? (i.e. an `input.date` added later to the DOM). I tried this (also, inside `$(document).ready`), but does not work:

```
$(document).on('ready', '.date', function(){
    $(this).datepicker({ ... });
});
```

**Notes**: The new input.date object is added to the dom via a call to `.html()` in an ancestor node. The content for the `.html` call is obtained by rendering a partial template from the backend.

Comment: Maybe the entity is not found when you call jQuery, so you should call it when the entity with the class date actually exists.

Comment: Do you want to convert future inputs to datepicker automatically without executing any code?

Comment: No, executing code. As the snippets I tried, but they did not work.

Comment: What about simply $('.date').datepicker({ ... }); ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same after calling .html() by finding ".date" classes.

```
$(parent).html(content).find('.date').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker({ ... });
});
```

Comment: Had to stick with this one

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [jQuery.initialize plugin](https://github.com/AdamPietrasiak/jquery.initialize) which is meant for similar use cases. It is based on MutationObserver as pointed out by @Roberto.

From the github page:

jquery.initialize plugin is created to help maintaining dynamically created elementes on page.

> It has exacly the same syntax like jQuery $elem.each function.
>
> The difference is that jQuery elem .each function is called only once
>   on elements that exist on page right now.
>
> .initialize function will call function again on new items matching
>   selecotr automatically just when they will be created by ajax or
>   pretty much anything you can imagine to add new elements to page.

**Initialize have exacly the same syntax as with .each function:**

```
$(".some-element").initialize( function(){
    $(this).css("color", "blue");
});
```

But now if new element matching .some-element selector will appear on page, it will be instanty initialized. The way new item is added is not important, you dont need to care about any callbacks etc.

```
$("<div/>").addClass('some-element').appendTo("body"); //new element will have blue color!
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the HTML from the backend via an ajax call from jquery, you can use an ajax global event to place your code there, for example, [ajaxSuccess()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) or [ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/).

Ej:

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    $(this).datepicker({ ... });
});
```

Otherwise, you could also use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FMutationObserver), if your target browsers support it. Example (From the linked MDN page):

```
var target = document;

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    $(this).datepicker({ ... });
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```